# How to add GUI elements in Windows 7 ( Like "this.add" in Android)

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, interface

In android when we want to add a GUI element on the screen we use

```
this.add
```

how can this be done in Windows phone 7 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dnt know much about Android, but In windows phone app if you want to add a UI element to the Screen:

First create the Element you want with all the properties set

```
Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "Click here";
button.Width = 100;
button.Height = 50;
```

And then add it to the XAML page

```
Grid.SetRow(button, 2); //here 2 is the row number in which you want to place your element
this.ContentPanel.Children.Add(button); //this adds the button to the "ContentPanel" grid
```

Adding to a StackPanel is much simpler when compared with Grid.

```
this.stackPanel.Children.Add(button); //where stackPanel is the name of the existing StackPanel
```

Go through the following links for adding elements to [GRID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271.aspx) and [STACKPANEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx)

Comment: :) You should know. You should know to which parent you want to add this child element to. And still if you dont, you create a new Stackpanel and add the child to the newly created stackpanel. But again, you have to add that new stackpanel to some parent in the page(May be to a GRID)